# Install OpenCL ubuntu AMD

Tags: opencl, ubuntu-14.04, gpu

I would like to install fglrx and use the GPU. But I didn't succeed to install it. I'm using ubuntu 14.04.03 Trusty.

Here the lspci output:

```
[thomas@elsa:~]$ lspci | grep -i --color 'vga'
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v3/4th 
Gen Core Processor Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 06)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] 
Oland XT [Radeon HD 8670 / R7 250/350]
```

I've tried to install it by following [this](http://amd-dev.wpengine.netdna-cdn.com/wordpress/media/2012/10/AMD_APP_SDK_InstallationNotes.pdf), [this](http://www2.ati.com/relnotes/amd-catalyst-graphics-driver-installer-notes-for-linux-operating-systems.pdf#page=19&zoom=auto,69,674) and [this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/AMD)

Did I miss something, should I install something else?

Any idea?

Thanks a lot

Comment: What error/issue is being faced ?

Comment: after I installed fglrx on ubuntu, when I reboot, i have a black screen. I didn't forget to do `sudo amdconfig --initial -f`. when I disintall flgrx, everything back to normal. What did I miss?

Answer (score 5):

**Display Drivers** : (Note: This is not a requirement for running OpenCL on an AMD GPU)

Here are some other links you can try for installing the AMD drivers:
[AMD Driver Install 1](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/AMD) and [AMD Driver Install 2](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1930450).

I've found (with Nvidia Drivers) that the black screen happens when X is not configured properly, so you have to follow those steps correctly.

The first link said to use `fglrxinfo` to check the status of the AMD drivers, so I assume that you don't get a black screen, check that the AMD drivers are working.

**OpenCL** : (Only requires AMD APP SDK)

To use the AMD GPU with OpenCL, you don't need the display drivers, (**Note** the part in the first document you referenced (the installation guide) which says *If Catalyst is not installed* on page 4 of 7), you just need the OpenCL runtime drivers (`libOpenCL` -- for running the compiled OpenCL code on the GPU) and the headers (for actually developing and compiling OpenCL code). Both of these come with AMD APP SDK. Just install the SDK as per the installation guide (try without the catalyst driver if you don't need the GPU for display).

Check that `/opt/AMDAPPSDK-3.0/` has the binaries, and it should include a `lib` directory where you can find `libOpenCL.so` and an `include/CL` where you can find all the header files.

Additionally, the SDK with have a `clinfo` binary (at least my installation on Arch does), in the `bin` directory of the SDK, so run:

```
/path/to/AMDAPPSDK/bin/clinfo
```

To check that your GPU can be detected. Here are some of the outputs of the `clinfo` command for my installation (detect Intel CPU):

```
Number of platforms:                 2
  Platform Profile:              FULL_PROFILE
  Platform Version:              OpenCL 2.0 AMD-APP (1800.8)
  Platform Name:                 AMD Accelerated Parallel Processing
  Platform Vendor:               Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
  Platform Extensions:               cl_khr_icd cl_amd_event_callback cl_amd_offline_devices 
  Platform Profile:              FULL_PROFILE
  Platform Version:              OpenCL 1.2 LINUX
  Platform Name:                 Intel(R) OpenCL
  Platform Vendor:               Intel(R) Corporation

# Some other information

# Information about a platform -- you should see AMD and Xeon
  Platform Name:                 AMD Accelerated Parallel Processing
Number of devices:               1
  Device Type:                   CL_DEVICE_TYPE_CPU
  Vendor ID:                     1002h
  Board name:                    
  Max compute units:                 8
  Max work items dimensions:             3
    Max work items[0]:               1024
    Max work items[1]:               1024
    Max work items[2]:               1024
  Max work group size:               1024

# Rest of information
```

Answer (score 3):

I have encountered the same problem with an AMD A10-6800K. The only solution for me to makes OpenCL working on that is:

1. Use Ubuntu 14.04 if you have a newer LTS. I have tried 16.04 and fglrx is no longer supported officially. I have no luck using the experimental AMDGPU-PRO or like. I end up install a new 14.04.
2. You need a driver. Install it directly from Ubuntu Software Center. You can also install it in "Additional Drivers". Do not download the latest driver from amd.com. It has compile errors. You may be able to find a solution finally. But if what you want to just do OpenCL coding, fall back to the Ubuntu one. Install clinfo and you should be able to find the GPU.
3. DO NOT use the OpenCL lib in AMD APP SDK 3.0. When you install the driver you already have an OpenCL lib in your system. I installed SDK 3.0 as root, which allows it to replace the old lib with the one shipped with SDK. And suddenly all OpenCL API call hang, including clinfo. I uninstall SDK and everything goes back to normal. This may also be caused by the driver I guess? Anyway, if you need SDK to compile the file, you can always install it as normal user.
4. Now clinfo should be working and enjoy OpenCL! BTW, the performance of AMD APU sucks when running OpenCL....